# Webpack error with react

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to configure webpack according to this [tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/setting-up-webpack-for-react-and-hot-module-replacement) and keep getting the same error.  I am having trouble debugging these 2 messages:

```
ERROR in ./app.js
Module parse failed: /path/react/react-webpack-babel/app/app.js Line 1: Unexpected reserved word
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from "react";
| import Greeting from "./greeting";
|

ERROR in ./index.html
Module parse failed: /path/react/react-webpack-babel/app/index.html Line 1: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <!DOCTYPE html>
| <html>
|
```

Here is my *webpack.configure.js*

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: {
    javascript: "./app.js",
    html: "./index.html"
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  },
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the *react components*

*app/greeting.js*

```
import React from "react/addons";

export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="greeting">
        Hello, {this.props.name}!
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

*app/app.js*

```
import React from "react/addons";
import Greeting from "./greeting";

React.render(
  <Greeting name="World"/>,
  document.body
);
```

*app/index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Webpack + React</title>
  </head>

  <body></body>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

In case it's helpful, here's my package.json with dependencies

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.22",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "webpack": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the `loaders` option should be nested in a `module` object like so:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: {
    javascript: "./app.js",
    html: "./index.html"
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I also added a missing semi-colon at the end ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been trying to understand how the hot module replacement works with webpack but was stuck on this part.  Thanks!!!

Comment: I've added the loaders in its correct position as per your answer, also added the semi-color, I'm still getting the same error, do you know if it could be due to any other reason?

Comment: @AbhinavSingi did you npm install the loaders? e.g. `npm install --save-dev babel-loader file-loader` or just `npm install` with Mdd's `package.json`?

Comment: @Almouro I did ```npm install``` . But if I specify the version no. in the former method - both should yield same results, right?

Comment: @Almouro apparently it's working fine now, I was ```require('webpack')``` in ```webpack.config.js``` which was causing some issues.

Comment: +100. You are the best. What a stupid mistake from me!

Answer (score 1):

When I was importing with the syntax

```
import Component from './components/component';
```

I was getting the module parse error. To fix it, I had to specify `.jsx` and it worked

```
import Component from `./components/component.jsx`.
```

It wasn't a config error at all. I'm on babel 6 with hot loader.